# magento - clean installation with products, customers and orders from old installation

Tags: magento, reinstall

i have magento 1.6.2 running on a dedicated server (ubuntu 10.04 lts)

I have tried various ways to upgrade magento to 1.7.0.2, but with no success.

Now i am thinking of installing a fresh magento 1.7.0.2 and rebuilding the shop.
This way i don't have the litter anymore of old deleted extensions.

But i want all my current data like products, orders, customers, mailinglist etc. imported in my new fresh installation.

How can i do this? Or isn't this a good idea?

I hope someone can help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it ...

A new installation will work in the following way ...

1. copy your db-base
2. copy your media folder to a new folder
3. than copy the fresh files downloaded from magento OS commerce to the server
4. install magento and fill in your db base credentials from point 1 ...
5. now you have a fresh installation, but with all your data (orders, customers, products, newsletters etc.)

Comment: Was this from same version to same version? Or was this to upgrade from a certain version to a newer version? If this was an upgrade, what version did you start and end with?

Comment: This. You could use for both. Basicly it renews all core files

Answer (score 1):

Try the Magento database repair tool:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

I would install over what you have got after removing tables/keys that don't need to be there. The above tool will enable you to identify what is to be deleted. It will also give you confidence in your db build.

Answer (score 1):

Not upgrading to latest version rather having a free install is doesn't seem to be a good idea because you can import all the products & Customers but there is no direct way to import the orders and other information on the fresh Installation.

I would personally suggest that you should once more try to upgrade to the latest version as I have upgraded several projects from Magento ver 1.6.2 to the latest and no such big issue occurred while upgrading.

Basic things you just need to keep in mind like keeping the back-up before upgrade and all..

Use the latest connect20 key for the upgrade i.e.

http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest

Hope this helps or you can tell the errors that you are facing during the upgrade.